# Using AJAX in Spring MVC View gives http.status as 404

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to use AJAX in a JSP View using Javascript. Following is my JSP code signup.jsp :

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var http;
function someAjax(){
    alert("ITS still WORKING");

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    **http.open("GET", "AjaxSameUser.jsp", true);**    
    alert("After connection");
    http.onreadystatechange=handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse(){
    alert("readyState :" + http.readyState+"   status : "+http.status);
    if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        alert("State as expected");
        document.getElementById("usernameExists").innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form:form commandName="user" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>    
            <td> Username : </td>
            <td> <form:input path="name" id="username" onchange="someAjax()" />  </td>   
              <td> <div id="usernameExists"> Something already </div></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

SameUser.jsp has some hard-coded data and it is in the same folder as signup.jsp.

I have checked http.readyState and http.status. readyState becomes 4, however status remains 404.

I know, every request for View must pass through the Controller in Spring MVC. But here why can't I directly call a JSP page from Javascript with no intervention of Spring?

Or rather how do I use AJAX in Spring MVC? I tried [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch11s05.html) link, but it says to use tiles and I am not familiar with it since I am new Spring.

Can anyone suggest some good way.

Comment: where is your AjaxSamUser.jsp? is it inside WEB-INF?

Comment: @thinksteep : No. It is in the same folder as signup.jsp. Both are in /WEB-INF/AllJsp/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's URL problem. Try to access your url directly from the browser (use firebug like addons for getting ajax urls). If the problem is with url then correct

`http.open("GET", "AjaxSameUser.jsp", true);`